# ZF2 - How to pass data from controller to helper

Tags: zend-framework2, helper

I need to pass data from controller to my custom view helper. I tried to do it in two ways, but unfortunately I can't make it working.
I have registered helper in module.config.php

**The first way** I tried to pass variables from controller to helper:
In my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{  
        $this->data = $this->getApplicationTable()->getTypes();

        $helper = new TestHelper();
        $helper->setVariables($this->data);
}
```

Here is my helper:

```
class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper {

    public $data;


    public function __invoke()
    {
        var_dump($this->data); // output null
        return $this->getView()->render('helper-view.phtml', $this->data);
    }



    public function setVariables($var)
    {
        if($var){
            $this->data = $var;
            var_dump($this->data) // output array with correct data
        }
    }



}
```

In layout, I display it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->testHelper(); ?>
```

And I got error from helper-view.phtml that variable is empty.

**The second way** I tried is based on dependency injection

My module.php:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Application\Model\ApplicationTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ApplicationTableGateway');
                    $table = new ApplicationTable($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
                'ApplicationTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    return new TableGateway('tableName', $dbAdapter);
                },
            ),
        );
    }

public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'TestHelper' => function ($helperPluginManager) {
                $sm = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('Application\Model\ApplicationTable');
                $viewHelper = new TestHelper();
                $viewHelper->setTableGateway($tableGateway);
                return $viewHelper;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

My Helper:

```
class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper {

    public $tableGateway;


    public function __invoke()
    {
        $data = $this->tableGateway->getTypes();

        return $this->getView()->render('helper-view.phtml', $data);
    }



    public function setTableGateway($tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }


}
```

I got same error as in first way.
I would be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: "error from helper-view.phtml that variable is empty."
Which variable is empty?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work, because the call $this->testHelper(); will create a new instance of TestHelper, which does not know about the $data, setVariables was never called for this instance.
Also I would not return the view inside the helper, leave this if possible in the controller. The helper is used to give helper methods for a view, consult the documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.advanced-usage.html#writing-custom-helpers

An easy solution, how to do this without DI: Give the desired data from the controller to the view, so the view can give the data to the helper if required:

Inside the indexAction, you set your data variable and give the variable to the view:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $data = $this->getApplicationTable()->getTypes();
    return new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array(
        'data' => $data,
    ));
}
```

Change your Helper: Remove the setVariables method and add in the signature of invoke the $data param. BTW, it is good practice to set the variable to private and add setters and getters.

```
class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper {

    private $_data;

    public function __invoke($data) {
        $this->setData($data);
        return var_dump($this->getData());
    }

    public function setData($data) {
        $this->_data = $data;
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->_data;
    }

}
```

Now, in your index.phtml you can get the $data from controller and pass it to the helper:

```
$data = $this->data;
echo $this->testHelper($data);
```

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I don't use view (index.phtml) in this action. It's kind of big map which doesn't have content, that's why I can't pass it from view

Comment: What exactly should happen on the indexAction? If you give me an explanation, I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I need to use helper to display checkboxes in layout(which looks like map). To do that I need to get informations from database and pass it to helper.

Comment: So you have a view output which is not connected to a Controller? For me this sounds like not following the MVC principles, or maybe I just don't get your intention. Probably it will be good to update the question with information, which shows, how exactly your view with the map is loaded and when, or on what event, the checkboxes need to be shown. Otherwise it will be difficult to give you the "right" solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with dependency injection, you need to pass the tableGateway as a parameter during construction. Otherwise, you can pass it during invocation. For the latter, if this is possible, do the following:

```
 class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper {

     public function __invoke($tableGateway)
     {
         $data = $tableGateway->getTypes();

         return $this->getView()->render('helper-view.phtml', $data);
     }
```

and in the layout:

> `<?php echo $this->testHelper($tableGateway); ?>`

Alternatively, for the approach with inserting it through the constructor:

```
public function getViewHelperConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'TestHelper' => function ($helperPluginManager) {
                $sm = $helperPluginManager->getServiceLocator();
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('Application\Model\ApplicationTable');
                $viewHelper = new TestHelper($tableGateway);
                return $viewHelper;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

and

```
class TestHelper extends AbstractHelper {
    protected $tableGateway;        

    public function __construct($tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $data = $this->tableGateway->getTypes();
        return $this->getView()->render('helper-view.phtml', $data);
    }

}
```

and in the layout:

> `<?php echo $this->testHelper(); ?>`

I don't have enough information or enough of your code to verify that this will work in your situation, but you can check out http://zendblog.shinymayhem.com/2013/09/using-servicemanager-as-inversion-of.html for more info on factories and dependency injection.